# Tips to use Android Studio

Tags: android, ide

I found it easier to understand the code when I know the hierarchy relationship between classes, so it would be helpful that anyone who points the path how to open the window which shows the hierarchy tree of a class as showed below:

Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images, [please click here to view the image....](http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/267603/2012012021594986.png)

Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 3):

**Navigate menu > Type Hierarchy.**

or Press **Ctrl+H**